# Calculate how close a number (in percentage) is between a range of two numbers

Tags: excel-formula, stock

I'm trying to calculate column F (current standing) where the current stock price lies between 52-week low and 52-week high numbers. Lower percentage means it's closer to the 52-week low and a high percentage means it's closer to the 52-week high.

In the first row (C2) below, the current price of the share ($68.56) is very close to the 52-week low number so I'm expecting the percentage to be low. In C3, the current price ($88) closer to the 52-week high number ($91.99) so the  percentage will be high as it's closer to the 52-week high.

I'm trying to coming up with this sheet to help which stocks are closer to the 52-week low and buy them. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Try  =(C2-D2)/(E2-D2)   and set column format to percentage